# How can i go to previous screen using static variable

Tags: java, android, constants, gesture-recognition, static-variables

I have problem implementing this since last 1 hour, I have more then 15 screen and slider menu as well in my code. What i am trying to achieve is when user swipe left a slider should open and when **user swipes right he/she should able to go to previous screen where he/she came from**.

So my problem start's here as i have implemented slider in my project so user can come from any screen out of 15 screen, so to handle this problem i took one static variable and increment it on each screen and then i have checked the value of static variable.

Based on static variable's value i am trying to move to previous screen but not able to do. I have implemented **SimpleGestureListener** in my code.

Following is my code.

```
public class ChangeWallpaper extends Activity implements OnClickListener,
        SimpleGestureListener {

//Declaration goes here
SimpleGestureFilter detector;
```

then inside onCreate method i have

```
detector = new SimpleGestureFilter(this, this);
```

and finally,

```
@Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent me) {
        // Call onTouchEvent of SimpleGestureFilter class
        this.detector.onTouchEvent(me);
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(me);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSwipe(int direction) {
        switch (direction) {

        case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_RIGHT:
            if (Const.prevNext == 1) {
                Intent profile = new Intent(ChangeWallpaper.this,
                        Profile_Detail.class);
                startActivity(profile);
                break;
            } else if (Const.prevNext == 3) {
                Intent comment = new Intent(ChangeWallpaper.this, Comment.class);
                startActivity(comment);
                break;
            } else if (Const.prevNext == 4) {
                Intent post = new Intent(ChangeWallpaper.this, Post.class);
                startActivity(post);
                break;
            } else if (Const.prevNext == 5) {
                Intent post2 = new Intent(ChangeWallpaper.this, Post_Two.class);
                startActivity(post2);
                break;
            } else if (Const.prevNext == 6) {
                Intent chat = new Intent(ChangeWallpaper.this, Chat.class);
                startActivity(chat);
                break;
            } else if (Const.prevNext == 7) {
                Intent following = new Intent(ChangeWallpaper.this,
                        Following.class);
                startActivity(following);
                break;
            } else if (Const.prevNext == 8) {
                Intent me = new Intent(ChangeWallpaper.this, Me.class);
                startActivity(me);
                break;
            } else if (Const.prevNext == 9) {
                Intent privacypolicy = new Intent(ChangeWallpaper.this,
                        PrivacyPolicy.class);
                startActivity(privacypolicy);
                break;
            } else if (Const.prevNext == 10) {
                Intent termscondition = new Intent(ChangeWallpaper.this,
                        TermsCondition.class);
                startActivity(termscondition);
                break;
            } else if (Const.prevNext == 11) {
                Intent contactus = new Intent(ChangeWallpaper.this,
                        ContactUs.class);
                startActivity(contactus);
                break;
            } else if (Const.prevNext == 12) {
                Intent moreOption = new Intent(ChangeWallpaper.this,
                        MoreOption.class);
                startActivity(moreOption);
                break;
            } else if (Const.prevNext == 13) {
                Intent whatsHot = new Intent(ChangeWallpaper.this,
                        WhatsHot.class);
                startActivity(whatsHot);
                break;
            } else if (Const.prevNext == 14) {
                Intent home = new Intent(ChangeWallpaper.this, Home.class);
                startActivity(home);
                break;
            }
            break;
        case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_LEFT:
            break;
        case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_DOWN:
            break;
        case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_UP:
            break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDoubleTap() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Double Tap", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

So you can check in above example like i have check, what is the value of my static variable but unfortunately i am not able to move to previous screen.

Or is there any better way then this method then please do suggest.

**Edit**

In my all other activity i have declare static variable as follow,

```
public class Home extends Activity{
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home);
        Const.prevNext = 1;
}
```

now in other class

```
public class Swp extends Activity{
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.swp);
        Const.prevNext = 2;
}
```

and so on.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: are you sure you initialized prevNext? Also the behaviour you are describing seems the one that ViewPager implements

Comment: @blackbelt, I have initialized prevNext in every activity's onCreate method like, `Const.prevNext = 1;` then in other file `Const.prevNext = 2;` and so on...

Comment: if you want to use variable across activities then tie it to Application class or just pass variable between activities. And again you should go with ViewPager instead of doing so

Comment: @InnocentKiller where you defined Const.prevNext , plus you are not assigning prevNext before starting activity plus overriding prevNext OnCreate which will lose prev value

Comment: @qwr, Const is a separate class for defining static variable, where i have defined it as a 0.

Comment: @InnocentKiller you can change prevvalue before starting activity. and this way you should not reassign PrevValue again inside OnCreate

Comment: @qwr, i didn't get your point, can you explain bit more.

Comment: @InnocentKiller According to what you write you should change Prevvalue only inside slidermenu. just before you choose to open  new activity. Cause it should hold previous not current. But in your example you are holding current activity when trying to assign  it inside OnCreate

Answer (score 0):

You need to also decrements the value of static variable when you go to the previous page.otherwise , it will increment again , and your logic will not work.Try this too before      startActivity(intent);

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Comment: If it increment again then also it should move to the wrong file, but it is not moving at all.

Comment: You just try this before startActivity .Sometimes this flag is required to work intent.                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);